# kendo ui treeview data from MVC controller

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, hierarchy

I have a stored proc that returns hierarchical data from SQL database using EF.
The treeview shows parent nodes only and non of the child nodes. I have been working on this problem for a while and nothing has come of it, it is frustrating. Thanks for any help I can get on this problem.

```
ParentId  Id         Title                         Level
--------- ---------- ----------------------------- ------
NULL      1          Chief Executive Officer       0
1         273        Vice President of Sales       1
273       16         Marketing Manager             2
273       274        North American Sales Manager  2
273       285        Pacific Sales Manager         2
16        23         Marketing Specialist          3
274       275        Sales Representative          3
274       276        Sales Representative          3
285       286        Sales Representative          3
```

At the service layer I have an orchestrator class that return the table above.

```
public IEnumerable<TreeviewItem> GetBusinessStructure()
{
    return Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<TreeviewItem>("spGetEmployees");
}
```

The model class

```
public class TreeviewItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual TreeviewItem Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TreeviewItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The controller

```
public JsonResult BusinessStructure(int? id)
    {
        var model = from e in        BusinessStructureOrchestrator.GetBusinessStructures()
                    where (id.HasValue ? e.ParentId == id : e.ParentId == null)
                    select new
                    {
                        id = e.Id,
                        Name = e.Name,
                        hasChildren = e.Children.Any()
                    };

        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The view

```
@model FilterBusinessStructureViewModel
<div class="form-group">

<label for="" class="col-sm-12 control-label">Choose Divisions/BUs/Sites</label>

<div class="col-sm-12">
    @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
            .Name("tvBusinessStructure")
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .Checkboxes(checkedboxes => checkedboxes
                .Name("SelectedDivision")
                .CheckChildren(true)
            )
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Model(m => m
                    .Id("Id")
                    .HasChildren("hasChildren")
                    .Children("Children"))
                    .Read(read => read
                                .Action("BusinessStructure", "Report")
                    )
            )
        )
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around and much trial and error I found a piece of code and modified it. The class used to traverse the hierarchy looks like this

```
public static class Treeview
{
    public static IList<TreeviewItem> BuildTree(this IEnumerable<TreeviewItem> source)
    {
        var groups = source.GroupBy(i => i.ParentId);

        var roots = groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key.HasValue == false).ToList();

        if (roots.Count > 0)
        {
            var dict = groups.Where(g => g.Key.HasValue).ToDictionary(g => g.Key.Value, g => g.ToList());
            for (int i = 0; i < roots.Count; i++)
                AddChildren(roots[i], dict);
        }

        return roots;
    }

    private static void AddChildren(TreeviewItem node, IDictionary<int, List<TreeviewItem>> source)
    {
        if (source.ContainsKey(node.Id))
        {
            node.Children = source[node.Id];
            for (int i = 0; i < node.Children.Count; i++)
                AddChildren(node.Children[i], source);
        }
        else
        {
            node.Children = new List<TreeviewItem>();
        }
    }

}
```

Then I made the following changes to the controller method

```
public JsonResult BusinessStructure(int? id)
    {

        List<BusinessStructureModel> businessStructures = BusinessStructureOrchestrator.GetBusinessStructures()
        .Select(e => new BusinessStructureModel
        {
            Id = e.ID,
            Name = e.Name,
            ParentId = e.ParentID
        })
        .BuildTree()
        .ToList();

        return Json(businessStructures, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```